# using cmake's target_compile_features with biicode

Tags: c++, cmake, biicode

I'm trying to use [target_compile_feature](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_compile_features.html) in my biicode block.
As far as I know, this is currently the best way to ask cmake for a specific c++ standard version, since it will know what (if any) flags to add to the compilation, and fail with an error if the compiler being used does not support the features we requested.

I added this line to my very simple CMakeLists.txt (no changes from the boost example in biicode's blog):

```
target_compile_features(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} PRIVATE cxx_auto_type)
```

When running bii build, I'm greeted with this error:

```
CMake Error at     bii_test/alchemist/blocks/sennin/deckbox_loader/CMakeLists.txt:13 (target_compile_features):
  target_compile_features may only be set INTERFACE properties on INTERFACE
  targets
```

Setting the cxx_auto_type at a PUBLIC or PRIVATE scope has exactly the same result.

I want to avoid using the [CXX_STANDARD](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) and CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED because the first is a soft request (if the requested standard is not supported cmake will still allow us to attempt to build the code) and the second enforces that there is someway to request full support for the whole requested standard standard (and in the case of Visual Studio, fail, because there is no such flag).

Comment: Just and advice on `TARGET_COMPILE_FEATURES`: I would be very cautious about it, even in the latest CMake, its data is partially implemented, which means that it will probably do not work properly for compilers as MinGW, Visual and possibly others. I suggest to double-check its behavior before relying on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about bii, but presumably `BII_BLOCK_TARGET` is something it provides? And you're supposed to use it with `target_link_libraries` or something?

Anyway, try the `INTERFACE` keyword.

```
target_compile_features(${BII_BLOCK_TARGET} INTERFACE cxx_auto_type)
```

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements

Comment: Yes, BII_BLOCK_TARGET is indeed an INTERFACE target to collect common properties for all the targets in a given block, the libraries and executables in it. So this should work, if the used compiler is actually managed by target_compile_features

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I have no way of checking at the moment. I will try it when I get back home.